# How to display four level pages category in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have two post types, one is products and another is brands and have a taxonomy product categories. How can I get a list of products with specific brand in specific product category

Comment: R u sure Brand is post type? I think it should be category so that we can get list of product with particular brand assigned to that. If brand is posttype than what is the relation between product and brand posttype.

Comment: I made new field Select brand in products and added the field type to post object

Comment: Hi and welcome on stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and add a minimal code example to this question so that your problem becomes understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should work.

```
$args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',                            
                        'include_children' => true
                    ),
                ),
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'meta_field_name_for_brand',
                        'value' => 'meta_value_saved_for_product_post',                         
                    )
                )
            );
$products = new WP_Query($args);
if($products->have_posts()) {

    while ( $products->have_posts() ) :

        $products->the_post();

        the_title();

    endwhile;
}
```